# Double-factor auth to unlock iPhone in general and, especially, Passwords app in particular?

Tags: authentication, ios, iphone

Is it possible to make iPhone require **both** FaceID **and** passcode when unlocking the device?

Especially the built-in password manager is guilty of relying solely on FaceID to pull up a password for a website or an app. I thought I could at least force it to use the passcode instead of FaceID by disabling FaceID for passwords, but instead it stopped requiring any kind of verification at all when the phone is unlocked! This is very insecure as there is no additional line of defence for if you forgot your phone unlocked or if it was locked, but someone unlocks it with your face or even a picture of your face.

Comment: What is Passwords app?

Comment: Built-in password manager on iOS

Comment: Ah. And no, you can't. If you want to enforce a password, you  need to disable FaceID in general (which, of course, has other downsides).

Comment: Face ID, if it’s working as designed, will not recognize a photo of your face, nor will it unlock the screen unless you’re looking at it.

Comment: @nohillside the thing is if you disable FaceID it does NOT enforce any auth to access the contents of the password manager - i.e. lockscreen is the only barrier at that point, and if the phone is unlocked, all passwords are in the open. It's either FaceID for password manager or nothing, per Apple.

Comment: You could also use a different password manager like 1Password (with the additional benefit of being cross-plattform).

Comment: yeah, I am going to switch. I just think it's really stupid on Apple's part to not offer this simple option.

Comment: Compulsory xkcd link - https://xkcd.com/538/